# Angularjs uses data-src automatically - want to use jquery.unveil.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image, lazy-loading

i what LazyLoading images with [Unveil](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) inside an Angular app. Unveil uses the real Image URL in data-src and can't use a custom "data attribute" like data-unveil.

The Problem is that Angular is automatically converting "data-src" to "src". WTF!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <ul>
        <li>Angular uses data-src as src attribute</li>
        <li ng-repeat="foo in ['Photo A', 'Photo B']">
            <img data-src="http://placehold.it/250x150&text={{foo}}" src="http://placehold.it/250x150&text=LazyLoad" />{{foo}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Changed "data-src" to "data-unveil", but unveil can't use it</li>
        <li ng-repeat="bar in ['Photo A', 'Photo B']">
            <img data-unveil="http://placehold.it/250x150&text={{bar}}" src="http://placehold.it/250x150&text=LazyLoad" />{{bar}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Angular is not automatically converting "data-src" to "src", I don't know what you are talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/a7doobqt/ (it would do that if for "data-ng-src", because that would conflict with the ngSrc directive, but that's not your case)

Comment: After running the snippet, the first img tag looks like this "<img data-src="http://placehold.it/250x150&amp;text={{foo}}" src="http://placehold.it/250x150&amp;text=Photo A">"

Comment: http://load.my-azur.de/f/o/2014-09-19_10-08-36_html%205%20template.png Without unveil!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a directive:

```
app.directive('unveil', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).unveil();            
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9KLLqHiT4KC2Z9onUizy?p=preview

Rule of thumb: always use directives if you want to integrate jquery plugins.

Answer (score 4):

If you have scope values like scope.url = 'www.myurl.com', and you want to to like this:

```
<img unveil data-src="{{url}}" src="placeholder.png">
```

That won't work because unveil does not understand {{url}}. Do it like this instead:

```
<img unveil unveil-source="{{url}}" unveil-source-retina="{{retinaUrl}}" src="placeholder.png">
```

With this directive:

```
app.directive('unveil', unveil);

function unveil() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            unveilSource: '@unveilSource',
            unveilSourceRetina: '@unveilSourceRetina'
        },
        link: link
    };
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        /* Set compiled src attributes before calling unveil */
        attrs.$set('dataSrc', scope.unveilSource || scope.unveilSourceRetina);
        attrs.$set('dataSrcRetina', scope.unveilSourceRetina);

        $(element).unveil();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ng-attr` instead.
`ng-attr-data-src='{{var}}'`